# Why error: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions:

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting the error in the last line. Both spreadsheets are in MyDrive
Don't know what to do to get permission. I am new to Google script.

```
function getUnstructured(){
    var ssThis=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qpjIBE_Y2u5NFJDX7hkCA_0SYOXC3lnL_vxh0e0xvlY");
```

Comment: There must be more to this because that looks okay to me.

Comment: there is more but the debugger stops with the var tss line highlighted. The error message in the title is what happens.

Answer (score 0):

/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
was at the top of my code. I thought it was a comment. when I removed it and ran the script I was prompted to grant permission. Now script runs.